# Android13でテザリングのON/OFFをアプリから切り替えたい。

Tags: android, wifi

AndroidStudioでAndroid開発をやっていますが、現在手動で行っているWiFiテザリングON/OFFをプロラムから行いたいです。
AndroidのバージョンによりWiFiテザリングON/OFFのやり方が変わっており、最近だとAndroid13ではConnectivityManager
でのON/OFFができなくなっているようです。
色々調べたのですがConnectivityManager→TetheringManagerに変更しないといけないようです。

TetheringManagerの使い方のサンプルがありましたら教えていただきたいです。

Answer (score 1):

以前のConnectivityManagerのやり方で、「システム設定の変更」の許可画面を出し
許可をもらえれば変更できるようになりました。
お騒がせしました。

「システム設定の変更」画面の表示方法

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS, Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName())); 
startActivity(intent);
```